# i am trying to store datatable pincode column in variable a call pincode on click of button

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

```
var pincode=$(this).closest('tr').children('td.pincode').text();
```

above code is working for non responsive datatable

but it is not working in responsive view of datatable is there any alternate solution to this code

[image: non responsive datatable]

[image: responsive datatable]

[image: responsive datable]

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
     "data": arr,
     "iDisplayLength": 10,
     "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
     "bDestroy": true,

     /* responsive: {
          details: {
              type: 'column',
              target: 'tr'
          }
      },*/
     responsive: true,

     columnDefs: [
         /*{
                                 className: 'control',
                                 orderable: false,
                                 targets: 0,
                                 visible:true
                             },*/

         {
             responsivePriority: 1,
             targets: 1
         },

         {
             "aTargets": [0],
             "sTitle": "Id",
             "class": "Id",
             "bSortable": true
         },
         {
             "aTargets": [1],
             "sTitle": "name",
             "class": "name",
             "bSortable": true
         },
         {
             "aTargets": [2],
             "sTitle": "gender",
             "class": "gender",
             "bSortable": true
         },
         {
             "aTargets": [3],
             "sTitle": "pincode",
             "class": "pincode",
             "bSortable": true
         },
         {
             "aTargets": [4],
             "sTitle": "City",
             "class": "City",
             "bSortable": true
         },
         {
             "aTargets": [5],
             "sTitle": "Action",
             "bSortable": true,

             "render": function(data, type, row) {
                 var returnHTML = CreateDataHTML(data);
                 return returnHTML;
             }

         }
     ],

     order: [1, 'asc']
 });
```

Comment: you have taken lots of efforts to write this question.

Comment: can you please share your JS code for datatable implementation?

Comment: it depends on the structure of the table when it's in responsive mode. You'll need to work out where the items are in relation to each other, or whether the item you want is hidden. Might be helpful if you would post a sample of the table structure in each mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your `datatable` initialization code you may try below code. Assuming that your line of code is written somewhere in button handler's code for the button present in each datatable row:

```
var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data(); //current row data
var pincode = data[3]; //pin code is at index 3
```

This should work for responsive as well as non responsive scenario.